# Homebrew's instructions to update Xcode CLT fail to address warning

Tags: xcode, homebrew

Since Catalina, `brew doctor` has produced the message

> Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.

Following the subsequent instructions to

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

has no effect.

How do I make sure that Homebrew recognizes that no newer version of the CLT are available?

---

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.2.17-72-ge4719cb
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew.git
HEAD: e4719cb6f3207a7aed932dbb9d6f363d6c478cd0
Last commit: 5 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 221abc864bb25f3c0bfa0b0f0237f426f0a056a3
Core tap last commit: 39 minutes ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_DISPLAY: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.R94NebSNsk/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
HOMEBREW_EDITOR: /usr/local/bin/bbedit
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 4
HOMEBREW_NO_ANALYTICS: set
HOMEBREW_NO_EMOJI: set
CPU: quad-core 64-bit haswell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 11.0 build 1103
Git: 2.26.2 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 1.8.0_172
macOS: 10.15.4-x86_64
CLT: 11.0.0.0.1.1567737322
Xcode: 11.5
XQuartz: 2.7.11 => /opt/X11
```

Comment: What is the output of `xcode-select -p` ?

Comment: @ankii: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Answer (score 1):

- https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/5002

This bug report, which is closed as expected behaviour, has this solution:

> **MikeMcQuaid**: Run xcode-select --install. If that doesn't work check for Mojave system updates. If that doesn't work reboot your machine and try both again. If that doesn't work try to download and install the latest CLT from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/more/

From the discussion under it, it seems you need to have both Xcode's CLT and the `/Library` CLT.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What should I do that I haven't yet done?

Comment: did you try downloading from apple site ?

Comment: A new version of CLT is now available in Updates. I'm not sure why Homebrew got ahead of Apple's own Update and was asking for that before it as available, but now it is.

Comment: Ah, thanks for confirming. But it could be that it is pushed via native apps later & made available on the web first.